# Understanding time-dependent forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, lie-derivative

If $w_{t}$ is a family of $l$-forms on a manifold $M$, how is the $l$-form $\frac{\text{d}w_{t}}{\text{d}t}$ defined?

For example, if we have a family of $1$-forms, $p$ a point in $M$ and $v$ an element of $T_{p}M$, $\frac{\text{d}w_{t}}{\text{d}t}(p)(v)$ should be a real number, so such derivative has to be evaluated in some point. Am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're wrong. A $1$-form needs to be evaluated on a tangent vector (field), not a function.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Although I still don't understand why is $\frac{\text{d}w_{t}}{\text{d}t}(p)(v)$ a real number, if $v$ is an element of $T_{p}(M)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just going back to the first definition. For each fixed $p\in M$,

$$\frac{ \omega_{t+h} (p) - \omega_t(p)}{h}$$

makes sense as $T^*_pM$ is a vector space. So by definition

$$ \frac{d\omega_t}{dt} (p)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{ \omega_{t+h} (p) - \omega_t(p)}{h}.$$

Basically you are thinking of, for each $p\in M$, $\omega_t (p)$ as a curve in $T_p^*M$.